# WebView returning blank post FB authorization

Tags: facebook, react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0, react-native-fbsdk

From my react native application, I am trying to authenticate against FB. Instead of directly using fbsdk, I was planning to use a wrapper around it.

I tried two wrappers.

- https://github.com/xxsnakerxx/react-native-social-auth
- https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login

In both cases, I end up with a WebView which won't callback the app.
I have raised two issues

https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login/issues/187
https://github.com/xxsnakerxx/react-native-social-auth/issues/6

XCode logs has below entries which I am not able to decipher

```
2016-12-09 06:13:29.757 XXXX[61829:8555589] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
2016-12-09 06:13:29.759 XXXX[61829:8555589] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

and..

__nw_socket_service_writes_block_invoke sendmsg(fd 9, 31 bytes): socket has been closed

```
2016-12-09 06:13:36.670958 XXXX[61829:8574160] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_error [15.1 157.240.7.20:443 cancelled socket-flow (null)] Socket protocol sent error: [32] Broken pipe
2016-12-09 06:13:36.671154 XXXX[61829:8574160] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_disconnected [15.1 157.240.7.20:443 cancelled socket-flow (null)] Output protocol disconnected
```

And the WebView post all the authentication looks like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eventually successful with `react-native-social-auth`. Missed a few configurations.